# Build Target for dronekit-sitl

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

How do you build Copter firmware for dronekit-sitl?  I can do either `make px4-v2` or `make sitl` but neither seems right.  The latest firmware dronekit sitl offers is 3.3 and I would like to try out 3.4 (and eventually make some of my own changes and try it out).

Answer (score 0):

After setting up sitl, the procedure to start it is as follows:

```
cd ardupilot/ArduCopter
sim_vehicle.py
```

All info is available on the wiki
http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/setting-up-sitl-on-linux.html

Comment: that's not for dronekit-sitl.  I suppose I could switch to using the ardupilot sitl, but I'm curious about dronekit-sitl specifically for now.